# If Statement to format a value depending on a Picklist value of another field

Tags: formula, inline-visualforce, formatting

Any Help would be much appreciated- I actually will be doing this for several different currency values If I could use a case statement even better. I know it should be in a class but I do not have that skillset.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(TEXT("{oppty.Local_Currency__c}) == 'CHF',"{0, number, ###.###,00}","{0, number, ###,###.00}")}" >
           <apex:param value="{!oppty.Selling_Price_Local__c}"/>
```

Comment: I just did a quick test for the format that I am trying and it will not work. we want to format with ###.###,00 for foreign currency and it will not allow that Error The number format pattern for <apex:outputText> is invalid.  We will not enable currency in the org I am working on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Either Apex or Javascript would be convenient here. Is either an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue was mostly due to getting the combination of single and double quotation marks wrong.

You also need to have curly brackets in three places - the outer evaluation marker, eg `value={!....`, and the two paramater parsing statements `{0,number,###.....`

Once those were fixed, I was able to get it to work.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(TEXT(Opportunity.Local_Currency__c) == 'CHF','{0, number, ###.###,00}','{0, number, ###,###.00}')}" >
    <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Amount}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```